# How to configure kong-api to communicate other spring Microservice

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kong

I am just started with Kong API with One API
I am able to run kong api locally using its official docker image available.
And on other side I am having another Spring-Boot microservice locally running inside same Docker engine.

Problem : What configuration needs in kong api yaml file so that I can connect to my spring-boot microservice ?

My kong -api yaml file

```
services:
- name: control-service-integration
  url: http://localhost:8080/
  plugins:
  - name: oneapi
    config:
      edgemicro_proxy: edgemicro_demo_v0
      add_application_id_header: true
      authentication:
        apikey:
          header_name: "x-api-key"
      upstream_auth:
        basic_auth:
          username: username
          password: password 
        
  routes:
  - name: control-service-route
    request_buffering: false
    response_buffering: false
    paths:
    - /edgemicro-demo-v0
```

From kon-one api service i am getting always 502 Bad Gateway error.
Let me know if anything information required.

Comment: what's the kong-one api? I could not find "oneapi" plugin on official kong documentation

Comment: Ohh My bad forgot to mention its actually only Kong API, I am updating the description.

Comment: It's quite unclear what exactly are you looking

Comment: Its already mention in the question how to connect from Kong API to locally running Microservice. do you know about Kong @sham ? I have to just make a slight configurational changes in YAML file so that it should reach to Microservice running on local machine.

Comment: still quite un clear about this config; 

`plugins:
  - name: oneapi`

Is there kong plugin with name `oneapi` or Is this your own custom plugin?

Comment: There should not be any concerns about plugins at all, those are additional tools to extends the Kong arms. the simple question in this topic is to connect locally running Microservice. Please do not get too much complicated in understanding.

Comment: Oh, sorry for confusion. I have never come across kong "oneapi"  and kong arms terms and also still could not find it on official documentation.

Comment: kong arms here meaning is to extends the functionality. I used a quite layman words to let you know. please maintain the professionalism It is really getting annoying now.

Comment: Ok..you could just say it's our own custom plugin..that's what I asked earlier..don't get annoyed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this
in above YAML

```
services:
- name: control-service-integration
  url: http://localhost:8080/
```

add this value in-front of url section `http://host.docker.internal:8080/` after doing lot of trials and errors finally now I am able to connect my app which is running on host.